# How to get item in set

Tags: python

Is there a way to 'get' the only item in a set without first casting it to a list?

```
s = set([u'http://imdb.com/title/tt0118583/'])
first_item = list(s)[0]
# u'http://imdb.com/title/tt0118583/'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `next(iter(setobj))` to get the only element:

```
>>> s = set([u'http://imdb.com/title/tt0118583/'])
>>> next(iter(s))
u'http://imdb.com/title/tt0118583/'
```

You can even specify a default for when the set is empty:

```
next(iter(setobj), None)
```

returns `None` if there is no element to return otherwise.